# Finding the Jordan form of $T(p(t))=p(t+1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

**Let $T:P_n(\mathbb{R})\to P_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a linear operator defined by $T(p(t))=p(t+1)$.**

**(a) Find the Jordan form for $T$.**

**(b) if $n=4$, find a base $B$ of $T$ such that $[T]_B$ is in the jordan form.**

My attempt:

Consider the standard base for $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ which is $A=\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}$, with this base, we have $T(1)=1, T(x)=x+1, T(x^2)=x^2+2x+1,...$ and so $[T]_A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & ... \\
0 & 1 & 2 & ... \\
0 & 0 & 1 & ... \\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... \\
\end{bmatrix}$

So I thought about finding the Jordan for using induction if $n=1$, it's trivial.

If $n=2$ we have $[T]_A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$and the jordan form is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

If $n=3$ then the jordam form is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &  \\
 & 1 & 1 \\
 &  & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ so on, I can say then that the jordan form is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &  &  &  &  \\
 & 1 & 1 &  &  &  \\
 &  & 1 & 1 &  &  \\
 &  &  & 1 & 1 &  \\
 &  &  &  & 1 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & ... \\
\end{bmatrix}$?

(b) If $n=4$ then $[T]_A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &1  & 1 \\
 & 1 & 2 &  3\\
 &  & 1 & 3 \\
 &  &  & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and the jordan form is $J=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &  &  \\
 & 1 & 1 &  \\
 &  & 1 & 1 \\
 &  &  & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, in this case we have that $P=\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 6 & 1 &  \\
 & 6 & 3 &  \\
 &  & 3 &  \\
 &  &  & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ is such that $PJP^{-1}=[T]_A$ then, we have that $B=\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 6 & 1 &  \\
 & 6 & 3 &  \\
 &  & 3 &  \\
 &  &  & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ is the base that solves the problem.

Is this correct? Thanks

Comment: Firstly, what is the dimension of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$, is it $n$ or $n+1$?
Did you try to find the eigenvectors of $T$? How did you conclude that what you wrote is indeed the Jordan form of $T$? You never explain your reasoning.

Comment: The only eigenvalue is $1$. The nullity of $A-I$ is easily seen to be $1$, so the Jordan form has a unique $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ block associated to $1$. Now find the basis in general, not just for $P_3$.

Comment: @Kolja  The dimension of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ is $n+1$, I'm taking $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ like the polynomials of degree $\leq n$. I found the eigenvalue of $T$, the only eigenvalue is $1$, I councluded that by looking the characteristic and minimal polynomial which is $(x-1)^k$ where $k=\dim(T)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Do you mean a general base not only for $P_4$?

Comment: Since you gave a $4\times 4$ matrix, and the dimension of $P_n$ is $n+1$, you gave a basis for $P_3$, not for $P_4$.

Comment: Incidentally, the $T - I$ operator is better known as $\Delta$ (where $\Delta p(t) = p(t+1) - p(t)$).  Using that, I think a general solution for the Jordan basis would be $\binom{t}{0}, \binom{t}{1}, \ldots, \binom{t}{n}$ where $\binom{t}{k} = \frac{t(t-1)\cdots(t-k+1)}{k!}$.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding part a: you haven't proved that your answer is correct. One way to **prove** that
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &  &  &  &  \\
 & 1 & 1 &  &  &  \\
 &  & 1 & 1 &  &  \\
 &  &  & 1 & 1 &  \\
 &  &  &  & 1 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the correct Jordan form is to show that $T$ (which is an operator over an $(n+1)$-dimensional space) satisfies $(T-I)^n \neq 0$ and $(T-I)^{n+1} = 0$ (where $I$ denotes the identity operator). Alternatively, it also suffices to show that $T$ has $1$ as its only eigenvalue and that the dimension of the kernel of $T-I$ is $1$.

Regarding part (b): your answer doesn't make sense; $B$ must be a basis of the space $P_4(\Bbb R)$, so it must consist of polynomials (i.e. "vectors" from the vector space $P_4(\Bbb R)$).

An easy way to find a Jordan basis is to find a vector $p \in P_4(\Bbb R)$ for which $(T-I)^n (p) \neq 0$. For this vector, the basis
$$
\{(T-I)^4(p),(T-I)^3(p), (T-I)^2(p), (T-I)(p),p\}
$$
is a Jordan basis.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be the dimension of $P_n(\mathbb{R})=\operatorname{Span}_\mathbb{R}(\{1,x,\ldots,x^{n-1}\})$.
I will not prove that $T$ is indeed linear.

Let us define
$$
p_k(x) = {x \choose k} = \frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-(k-1))}{k!}.
$$
For example this definition sets $p_0(x) = 1$ and $p_1(x) = x$.

I argue that $\{p_k(x)\}_{k=0}^{n-1}$ is a basis of generalised eigenvectors of $T$, and that $T(p_k) = p_k + p_{k-1}$ for $k\geq 1$ (together with $T(p_0)=p_0$).
$$
T(p_k) = {x+1 \choose k} = {x \choose k} + {x \choose k-1}
$$
This will remind you of [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule), and indeed it is the same thing.
If you're not convinced, just expand it
$$
{x+1 \choose k} = \frac{(x+1)x (x-1)\cdots (x+1-(k-1))}{k!} = \frac{(x+1)x (x-1)\cdots (x-(k-2))}{k!}
$$
Write $x+1 = (x-(k-1)) +  k$ and expand to get
$$
\frac{(x -(k-1)) x (x-1)\cdots (x-(k-2))}{k!} + \frac{ k x (x-1)\cdots (x+1-(k-1))}{k!} =
$$

$$\frac{x (x-1)\cdots (x-(k-2))(x-(k-1))}{k!}  + \frac{x (x-1)\cdots (x-(k-1)-1)}{(k-1)!}=
$$
$$ 
={x \choose k} + {x \choose k-1}.
$$